# Помогите разобраться с потоками в python

Tags: python, telegram-bot

пытаюсь запусть несколько телеграм ботов одним файлом. делаю это так...

```
    import threading

    def action():
        import bot1 
    def action(): 
        import bot2 
    def action():
        import bot3 
    def action(): 
        import bot4 
    def action():
        import bot5 

    for _ in range(5):
        t = threading.Thread(target=action)
        t.start()
```

так вот... работают не все, точнее три, другие два спят... что не так?

Comment: Замечание: функций у вас 5, но так как отчет Python ведёт с нуля, то range надо установить на 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы всем функциям дали одинаковое название.

Вообще, это не очень хорошая практика - делать модули, которые выполняют какую-то работу сразу в момент импортирования. Гораздо более правильный вариант, это делать в модуле класс или функцию, которые уже после импорта явно применить.

Выглядеть это может примерно так:

```
import threading
from bot1 import start_bot1
from bot2 import start_bot2
from bot3 import start_bot3
from bot4 import start_bot4
from bot5 import start_bot5


bots = [start_bot1, start_bot2, start_bot3, start_bot4, start_bot5]

for i in range(5):
        t = threading.Thread(target=bots[i])
        t.start()
```

Comment: Лучше `for i in bots: t = threading.Thread(target=i())`

Comment: @Alban, согласен, это я стормозил ))

Comment: всё заработало! моей радости нет предела! ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО ВСЕМ!!!

Comment: @Саня [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)